# Thread Pooling with Arrays in C#, index is out of range

Tags: c#, threadpool, indexoutofboundsexception

I have been trying to use thread pooling on image filtering where the method takes out the red color from an image and returns the filtered image. I get an error when y variable reaches the max amount. I have been looking for answers but couldn't find anything related to this.

```
public Color[,] Apply(Color[,] input)
{
    int width = input.GetLength(0);
    int height = input.GetLength(1);
    Color[,] result = new Color[width, height];

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Work(x, y));
        }
    }

    void Work(int x, int y)
    {
        var p = input[x, y];
        result[x, y] = Color.FromArgb(p.A, 0, p.G, p.B);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: This isn't the cause of your current problem, but note that you return `result` potentially before all of the jobs you posted to `ThreadPool.QueueUseWorkItem` have completed

Comment: Google "capture for loop variable considered harmful".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```cs
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Work(x, y));
```

`x` and `y` are *captured* - when the task runs (at some point in the future), they (`x` and `y`) won't have the values you're thinking of - they will have moved on. Define your own locals **in the same scope**:

```cs
var xx = x;
var yy = y;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Work(xx, yy));
```

Comment: Specifically, at some point, `y` will be captured and then incremented so that it's equal to `height`. When `Work` executes, `y` will be `height`, and this causes your exception

Comment: I tried this before and got an error. Now, I try again after you mentioned it and it worked. Software is definitly magic. I appreciate your effort. Have a nice day!

Comment: @ErkanGÖRGÜLÜ where exactly you declare he locals is very important. Declaration scope defines lifetime (so: which values are shared) for capture contexts.

Comment: @ErkanGÖRGÜLÜ This is racy, as well. If `Work` is executed before the next loop iteration, you're fine. If you get a loop iteration which pushes `y` up to `height` before `Work` executes, then you've got a problem.

Comment: @canton7 since we're snapshotting inside the innermost part of the loop, I'm not sure what you mean there

Comment: @Marc I mean, the code in the question, without your fix. That wasn't at all clear, in hindsight...